# PHPMailer sometimes throws "SMTP server error: authentication required"

Tags: php, phpmailer

Using GoDaddy hosting, I have a PHP script to send emails. Now, it works great most of the time, but sometimes, it is giving me the message "SMTP server error: authentication required" and failing to send the mail.

Why is this happening and is there any way to fix it?

Heres the code:

```
<?php

if (!class_exists('PHPMailer'))
    include("class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
$mail->Port = 80;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Subject = "$subject - $dealer_name";
$mail->Password = "mypassword";

if ($id_dealership == 77) 
    $mail->Subject = "$subject - $dealer_name (Unassigned) - $website";
else            
    $mail->Subject = "$subject - $dealer_name";

if ($id_dealership == 30 || $id_dealership == 146) 
{
    $from_email = 'myemail1@domain.com';
    $from_email2 = 'myemail2@domain.com';
}
else if ($id_dealership == 207) 
{
    $from_email = 'myemail3@domain.com';
    $from_email2 = 'myemail4@domain.com';
}
else
{
    $from_email = 'myemail5@domain.com';
    $from_email2 = 'myemail6@domain.com';
}

$mail->Username = $from_email;
$mail->setFrom($from_email, 'Our Company'); 
$mail->AddAddress($from_email);

if ($id_dealership == 159)  
    $mail->Body = $msg_xml2;        
else if ($id_dealership == 83)
    $mail->Body = $msg_xml;
else
    $mail->Body = $msg;

foreach ($dealer_email as $k => $v)
{
    $v = trim($v);
    $mail->AddAddress($v);
}

if (!$mail->send())
{
    $mail->Username = $from_email2;
    $mail->setFrom($from_email2, 'Our Company');    
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();

    foreach ($dealer_email as $k => $v)
    {
        $v = trim($v);
        $mail->AddAddress($v);
    }

    $mail->AddAddress($from_email2);

    if (!$mail->send())
    {
        mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'Mail not sent to dealer '.$id_dealership, "lead id ".$id_lead."\n\nError: ".$mail->ErrorInfo, 'From: ourcompany@domain.com');
    }
}

?>
```

Note: the password is the same for all $from_email's used.

Comment: Your current sending page please?

Comment: It's probably a problem with GoDaddy. You should use a different/more reliable SMTP server.

Comment: Can we see the script? I can not help you without the code.

Comment: i just posted the code

Answer (score 0):

Like @Abhi Beckert said, you should check with GoDaddy.
But, if you're using "mail()", you could try to check for errors and retry to send the email to see if it works when you get that random error.

```
if (!mail(...)) {
   // retry or reschedule for later (or maybe sleep for a couple of seconds)
}
```

I would give this a shot, maybe try 4-5 times when you get an error with 2-3 seconds of sleep() in between. If this works, that's an ugly fix and you should probably get something more reliable or ask GoDaddy to fix it.

Comment: GoDaddy does not support mail() well. They haven't disabled the function, but their server simply will not send mail via PHP's built-in function if the From address is any domain on any of their servers. You have to use SMTP if you want to send mail while hosted with them.

Answer (score 0):

Without your code i can not give you the answer but I can guess.

I am guessing you are sending mail with `mail`. What the error is telling you is that you have to use smtp and it has to be authorized. It is like a login for the server to send emails.

For SMTP you should use a library such as [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [phpmailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer)